# Can i find similar players using a clustering method like the k-mean algorithm?

Tags: clustering, recommender-system

I am working on a data mining project on NBA data. I want to make a recommendation system similar to the google one, where you search for players and you get recommendation for similar players. I intend to make such system based on their stats. My data looks like [this](https://github.com/joed7/Data-Mining-Project/blob/master/data/active.csv)

```
14  Tony Allen  709     357     15386   2178    4580    0.476   102     363     0.281   2076    4217    0.492   0.487   1220    1701    0.717   804     1567    2371    942     995     299     964     1675    5678

15  Al-Farouq Aminu     431     228     9988    1119    2592    0.432   188     607     0.31    931     1985    0.469   0.468   530     731     0.725   618     1724    2342    488     413     245     540     813     2956
```

One approach I have in mind is using k-means clustering, but I am not sure how I will use the clusters to find similar players. Each cluster will have hundreds of players, I will need further filtering.

Does anybody have any suggestions/tips for handling this problem?

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Do you want a solution on in the clustering approach?  As I see it, a basic collaborative filtering algo. would do better on this data :)

Comment: @Dawny33 you are right collaborative filtering will work better. But, is there any knowledge I can extract using cluster.  I am asking because as part of the project, I am applying various Machine learning techniques and determine their applications.

Answer (score 3):

For **finding similar** objects, k-means does not make much sense.

k-means is based on similar objects. If squared deviations don't work for your data then k-means will not work either.

Thus, instead of using k-means, just use a **nearest neighbor search** without k-means.

Comment: So should I run nearest neighbour search for each player to find similar players? I have over 2000 players.

Comment: Yes, that is the canonical approach. 2000 is tiny.

Comment: Okay Thanks. Could you elaborate on your comment "k-means is based on similar object"?

Comment: k-means computes a lot of similarities, too. If you have 20 clusters and 100 iterations until converge, it is as expensive as comparing every player to every other player in your case. Except that k-means only work woth squared deviations, but you may need to choose a more advanced similarity.

Answer (score 2):

You can go as further or specific you want with this kind of data.
I would suggest first to analyze the data thoroughly before deciding which algorithms to apply. Evaluate the mean, quartiles, max and min of each parameter (such as in a box plot), verify if you have missing values and in that case decide a way of dealing with that (removing data, imputating - predicting missing value from data - or average, as common techniques). Also verify if is possible to create a new representative feature from the information you have, or even mix a set of features to reduce (a priori feature selection; just ok if it makes a lot of sense from your knowledge on the context - NBA). For example, a player position can be considerably representative, in the sense of giving context to data (e.g. it will come up that defensive players steal more balls than attacking players but score less).

Afterwards I would suggest some simple algorithms such as:

- **Hierarchical clustering**:  can help you to build a genealogy of players, so you see which ones cluster together directly and which others influence this cluster (so they are similar in certain more general aspects but not so much so to be clustered together).
- **K-Means**: Well, its always good to try it; it won't be that expensive in computational terms. The thing is that determining K will be rather complicated, but it can give you hints from a Visualization point of view, while not actually helping directly the task of information retrieval.
- **K-Nearest-Neighbors**: Also determining K is complex (but not that much) it can give a first hint for retrieving similar players based on their distance in the space. This is a form of case-based reasoning, but actually is quite practical for your purposes. The key thing here is determining the right distance measure. Start with Euclidean as a typical approach. Then you can try some other distance measures such as the Malahanobis Distance, which takes into account the covariance of features.

You can have a first glance and even a functional solution following these approaches. Once observing the results you can get deeper (if necessary).

Remember to normalize or standarize the data previously. You could also visualize the first principal components after applying PCA or LDA (this last if you have a target variable) so to observe how well the data distributes.

The same methods can be applied after refining the data through feature selection and/or extraction techniques; which in some cases produces very interesting results.

Comment: I disagree: trying k-means is a waste of time if it does not help your objective...

Comment: Ok, just edited the comment. What I mean is that it can be helpful to visualize and understand the data a bit more. Definitely it won't help directly to a retrieval task; however, it is always useful to try to understand if the data is giving you hints of clear groupings or  not.